How to determine if a large integer is a power of 3 in Python?
I'm trying to determine if a given positive integer ( N ) is a power of 3, i.e., if there exists a nonnegative integer ( x ) such that ( 3^x = N ). The challenge is that ( N ) can be extremely large, with up to ( 10^7 ) digits.
Here's the logic I want to implement:

If ( N ) is less than or equal to 0, return -1.
Use logarithmic calculations to determine if ( N ) is a power of 3.
If it is a power of 3, print the value of ( x ); otherwise, print -1.

I've tried the following code, but I'm concerned about precision issues with large integers:
import math

def is_power_of_three(N):
    if N <= 0:
        return -1
    log3_N = math.log10(N) / math.log10(3)
    if abs(log3_N - round(log3_N)) < 1e-10:
        return int(round(log3_N))
    else:
        return -1

# Example usage:
N = int(input("Enter a number: "))
print(is_power_of_three(N))

Question:

Is there a more efficient way to check if ( N ) is a power of 3, especially for very large values?
How can I handle precision issues in Python when calculating logarithms for such large integers?
Are there alternative methods to achieve the same goal?


Do you need to find out whether it is one or which one it is?

Is this online somewhere for trying it ourselves?

You're asking about given N, which in your code is an int. Is that really the task? Or is what's really given a string (as your example usage somewhat suggests)?

Question 1 doesn't make much sense... Asking for something more efficient than something that is wrong. The answer is pretty much "no", but that's just because yours is extremely fast by being wrong.

Lots of good ideas on How to check if an integer is a power of 3?

@wim Are any of them good for such large numbers? I didn't see any when I checked earlier, but I didn't check all of them.

I don't see anything as good as nneonneo's answer below. A bunch of interesting alternative ideas though.

Consider the last digit of 3**k.

@lastchance How much does that help?

@no comment, for 60% of input strings it will exclude the input before you even convert it to an integer. For the others, well, eventually, you will actually have to look for powers of 3**4 or 81, and every power of that ends in 1.

@Adel Are you still alive? Why are you not responding to questions? https://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive

Consider the last [decimal] digit of 3**k (lastchance) similarly, no integer with an odd tens digit is an integral power of 3.

Any approach that involves repeated division is going to be slow with numbers that large.
Instead, consider using the bit length of the number (effectively the ceiling of its base 2 logarithm) to approximate the corresponding power of three, then check to see if it is indeed equal:
import math
def what_power_of_3(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return -1
    k = math.floor(n.bit_length() * (math.log(2) / math.log(3)))
    if n == 3**k:
        return k
    else:
        return -1

This is fast: the test requires only a single exponentiation, so for e.g. 3**10000000, it requires only a few seconds on my smartphone.

A brief sketch to show why this is correct:
Because of the equality check, if n is not a power of 3, the answer will always be correct (because n == 3**k cannot be true). So it suffices to prove that this answer always finds the correct k when n == 3 ** k. Let k > 0, n = 3 ** k, and t = n.bit_length(). Then, 3 ** k < 2 ** t < 3 ** (k + 1) by definition of bit_length(). Thus k < t * log(2) / log(3) < k + 1, and so n.bit_length() * (math.log(2) / math.log(3)) is going to be a fractional value that lies strictly between k and k+1; thus, the floor of that value will be exactly k.

Oh damn, it takes only 0.02s on my desktop. You won, nice answer

Very elegant, and returns the values requested by the question in excellent time, on my end. I did 3**1000000 in about a second flat.

Question 1: Why not k = math.floor(math.log(n, 3))?

@Mike What monster desktop do you have?

@nocomment because that doesn't work properly. For example, math.log(3**1000330, 3) == 1000329.9999999999. It results in having to test two values rather than just one. My approach works for all integers up to ~2**(2**52) (a number that would take over 500 TiB to store).

Ok that partially answers my second question: why your way works. That's still not clear to me.

Oh and I think the floor() is the problem, k = round(math.log(n, 3)) seems to work well.

@nocomment I've added a sketch of a proof to the answer. I think k = round(math.log(n, 3)) should work too.

Thanks. Mathematically, it looks good. But with floats, I'm still not entirely sure.

I just reread the question: it already used round(log3_N)). You suggest to use something else instead... I think then you should say why yours is better.

t*log(2)/log(3) is a float and potentially very very large. Are you sure that the accuracy with which it is held would give the correct floor value?

@lastchance why would it be large? For a 10-million-digit number, it will be on the order of 30 million, which is well within the precision of a 64-bit float (which is what Python uses for the float datatype).

I'm other words, this looks like you're responding to the other answers instead of to the question, and are rather ignoring the question. The question doesn't use repeated division, and it already does approximate the corresponding power of 3. Really what you contribute is not those things but only the n == 3**k check, which you barely mention. And in general, like I said, when replacing something from the question's code (in this case how you compute k), one should say why. Don't change something good for no reason.

shrug it's code I use to solve this type of problem. It works. x.bit_length() * const is even a teensy bit faster than math.log(x, base), although the efficiency gain there is rather outweighed by the computation of 3 ** k; nevertheless, I habitually reach for n.bit_length() when it makes sense to use. You're welcome to write your own answer, if you're unhappy with this one.

I might if they clarify/fix the question as requested, but it looks like they abandoned it and us already.

OK, I accept your reasoning @nneonneo. Yours is a great answer and very fast. I just get a bit jumpy with the accuracy of floats (having been bitten once or twice before.)

@lastchance I've addressed computing log3(n) without floating point precision issues in my answer if you care to have a look.

@nocomment you may be interested as well, since you expressed concern over the accuracy too

As the comments in the existing answers highlight, things get a bit iffy once you bring floating point precision into a problem with large integers. Even if the bounds are safe in practice, I'd personally rather avoid floats, as demonstrated below.
I compute the base 3 logarithm of the integer from its last O(log(log(N)) bits using some number theory and abstract algebra. The basic observation is that 3 is a generator of the cyclic group <3> modulo 2^(K+2) with order 2^K. This means we pick K such that 2^K is equal to or greater than log3(N), then compute the discrete logarithm of N mod 2^(K+2), and we get the answer to log3(N). I compute the discrete logarithm bit by bit, in O(b^2) operations (assuming multiplication is constant time, due to the small size of integers it operates on), or O(log(log(N))^2) time (if we really want to factor in the time of multiplications it comes out to O(log(log(N))^3 log(log(log(N))) log(log(log(log(N)))))).
First, we have a helper function for computing the countth squaring of a base base modulo m. Here I pass a bit mask mask = m - 1, since the modulus is a power of two, so we can do the reduction in constant time (or linear in log(log(N)), if you want to be precise).
def nsqr(base, count, mask):
    for _ in range(count):
        base &= mask
        base *= base
    return base & mask

Next is the computation of the discrete logarithm itself. The function takes the power of three itself, pow3, and the log2 of the desired group order, ord_exp.
def dlog3m2x(pow3, ord_exp):
    mod = 1 << (ord_exp + 2)
    mod_mask = mod - 1
    
    root1 = nsqr(3, ord_exp - 1, mod_mask)
    inv_3_pow = pow(3, -1, mod)
    
    result = 0
    for i in range(ord_exp):
        if nsqr(pow3, ord_exp - 1 - i, mod_mask) == root1:
            pow3 *= inv_3_pow
            pow3 &= mod_mask
            result |= 1 << i
            
        inv_3_pow *= inv_3_pow
        inv_3_pow &= mod_mask
        
    return result

Lastly, we have the high level wrapper around this, which takes just a power of three, and computes log3(N) using the discrete logarithm helper.
def ilog3(pow3):
    exp_max = pow3.bit_length()
    ord_exp = exp_max.bit_length()
    return dlog3m2x(pow3, ord_exp)

I've verified the correctness of this up to 3^20000, and also benchmarked individual larger values up to 3^20000000. Even for N=3^20000000, it returns the correct log3(N) (without using floats) in less than a thousandth of a second on my machine. It took far longer to just pre-compute N itself to hand off to function to benchmark.
Regarding the original question, the solution would be similar to the top answer currently (which uses floating point arithmetic), and just check pow(3, ilog3(N)) == N. I'd recommend either implementing an early-exit into the power function, or checking that the computed ilog3(N) (which is only correct for N=3^x exact) is not larger than a safe estimate ilog3(N) < N.bit_length(), otherwise you may end up computing a ridiculously large bogus value to find it does not in fact equal N.
def is_pow3(n):
    x = ilog3(n)
    if x >= n.bit_length():
        return False
    return 3 ** x == n

You can also speedup the rejections by reducing N modulo 2^M for some smallish M such that ceil(log2(log2(N))) < M < floor(log2(N)), and verifying 3^ilog3(N) mod 2^M (computed with modular exponentiation by squaring) against that. This will help dramatically with speeding up rejection of random non-powers-of-three, but validating actual perfect powers of 3 will still require a full exponentiation.
def is_pow3_ff(n):
    x = ilog3(n)

    if x >= n.bit_length():
        return False
    
    exp_max = n.bit_length()
    ord_exp = exp_max.bit_length()
    
    mod = 1 << min(exp_max, ord_exp * 8)
    mod_mask = mod - 1
    
    if pow(3, x, mod) != n & mod_mask:
        return False
        
    return 3 ** x == n

You can of course choose a different threshold, balancing the expense of computing O(log2(x)) multiplications of M bit numbers with the chance of M-K bits just so happening to match the corresponding bits of N.

Love the clever application of number theory here, very nice. I wonder if we could test the equality of the power by verifying the remainder modulo a sufficient number of primes (such that the product of the primes exceeds N, by the Chinese Remainder Theorem). If we choose the primes carefully (such that it's easy to calculate the modulus), maybe this will be efficient.

@nneonneo probably.  Computing pow(3, x, m) will be easy since we can even reduce the exponent mod λ(m) (λ(x) is the carmichael function), so it'll come down to efficiently computing N mod m. For modulus m = 2^y - 1, we can just sum the y-bit "digits" of the base 2^y number to get N mod m very easily. This means just picking a bunch of coprime 2^y-1 values, optionally factoring them beforehand, and computing residues and applying CRT as you mention.

By the way I think you should mention that the output of ilog3 is totally bogus if the input is not a power of three - it's not a drop-in integer replacement for log(x, 3).

@nneonneo Isn't that what the part with "only correct for N=3^x exact" and "otherwise you may end up computing a ridiculously large bogus value" is talking about?

@nocomment I think this doesn't quite capture how wrong the result can be for non-powers-of-3. First, the design of ilog3 bounds the output exponent such that you won't likely calculate a "ridiculously large bogus value". Second, it's "only correct for N=3^x", but for N != 3^x, the result is essentially random due to the properties of discrete logarithms. The statements there make it sound a bit like it's only going to be inexact.

In any case, my comment there wasn't meant to denigrate the question - as I mentioned above, I think this is a very clever, fast and accurate solution. It's meant to caution folks who might try to use ilog3 in other contexts, and be surprised that e.g. ilog3(6563) == 9 (close!) yet ilog3(6567) == 6. The use of modular discrete log produces essentially unpredictable results for non-powers, which are not going to be obvious for people who haven't worked with them.

Variation computing the candidate power myself with exponentiation by squaring. A bit slower than **, which uses a faster algorithm.

@nocomment this (and your earlier version) are correct. The order / cycle length of 3 mod 2^(k+2) is 2^k, so yes, your last k+2 bits can be used to uniquely match the 2^k power.

@nocomment my concern is the speed of rejections. You have to compute the full exponentiation of a number comparable in size to N itself in order to determine that its not a power of three. When we compute the candidate ilog3(N) quickly on small numbers, we can easily early-exit by checking other bits mod (2^a) or mod (2^b - 1), by cheap modular exponentiation by squaring.

Your function can be adapted to do this more efficiently than my code above however: you just need to truncate your P value to some safe upper bound on log2(log3(N)) bits (as I do in my answer). Exit when either P matches the trailing bits of N, or neither P*P nor P*P*p match the expected number of intermediate bits.

@DillonDavis Thanks. Yes, I tried adding if n & m != P & m: return False after the P *= p and considered something like what you just described, but yours is faster anyway, so ... meh.

Your function should be returning a boolean. Returning a "sentinel value" of -1 seems odd and non-idiomatic.
An alternative approach to using logarithms is to use repeated division. Because we are dividing down by the base, the runtime complexity is logarithmic (worse though for very large numbers).
def is_power_of(n, d):
    if n == 1: return True
    if n < d: return False
    while n >= d:
        if n % d: return False
        if n == d: return True
        n //= d
    return False

Now, if you need to know which power of three the number is and that's why you're returning -1, then I would still suggest you don't want to return -1 but rather None. And that you use a different function name.
def power_of(n, d):
    if n == 1: return 0
    if n < d: return None
    exp = 1
    while n >= d:
        if n % d: return None
        if n == d: return exp
        exp += 1
        n //= d
    return None


It looks like a reasonable approach for small numbers, but the question is specifically about large numbers.

different function name power_of(n, d) or maybe integral_logarithm(n, b) or maybe discrete_logarithm(n, b).

I'm going to quibble with your calling this "logarithmic".  Typically for problems involving numbers, "n" is the number of digits in the number, not the number itself.  So your algorithm is linear.

This isn't going to match nneonneo for speed. It is, however, an attempt to stay entirely within integer arithmetic, albeit (possibly) requiring O(log(N)) divisions.
One point to note: if you took a large number the overwhelming likelihood is that it ISN'T a power of 3. Thus, you should exclude as fast as possible: possibly before converting your input string to an integer in the first place.
NEW VERSION
Any power of 3 is of the form 3**(4k+m), where m is 0, 1, 2  or 3. In decimal (but see below) the corresponding last digit for each value of m is 1, 3, 9 or 7. Any other digit ending can be rejected immediately.
If it ends in 1 then check whether x is a power of 3**4, i.e. 81
If it ends in 3 then check whether x is divisible by 3 and x/3 is a power of 81.
If it ends in 9 then check whether x is divisible by 9 and x/9 is a power of 81.
If it ends in 7 then check whether x is divisible by 27 and x/27 is a power of 81.
Similar things happen in hexadecimal. Here the last hexadecimal digits are 0x1, 0x3, 0x9, 0xB. This makes it possible to exploit bit operations to get the last hexadecimal digit rather than doing expensive divisions.
So, apart from the initial last-digit check, you are asking if something is a power of 81. Moreover, every power of 81 ends in the hexadecimal digit 1.
User M.C. Escher gave me the clue for the next part. He wanted to store ALL powers of 3, but, in fact, you only need to store a few of them: 3, 3^2, 3^4, 3^8, 3^16, ..... In my case, with powers of 81 instead of 3, I only need to store about 24 of them.
In the following code the pre-computation of powers takes a little time and a modest space - but not excessively so. It could be done outside the program with the array of 24 numbers stored in a file, say.
The program can now get to a number with 1e7 digits, the largest power being of order 3^(2.1e7).
################ PRE-COMPUTATION ############
print( "Pre-computation starts ..." )
powers = [81]
for k in range( 1, 24 ):
    powers.append( powers[-1] * powers[-1] )
print( "... pre-computation ends" )
#############################################


def power_of_eightyone( x ):
    exponent = 0
    if x == 1: return 0
    while x > 1:
       if x < 81: return -1            # definitely not a power
       if x & 0xF != 1: return -1      # last hexadecimal digit must be 1
       k = 0
       while x >= powers[k]: k += 1
       k -= 1
       xnew = x // powers[k]
       if xnew * powers[k] != x: return -1
       x = xnew
       exponent += 2 ** k
    return exponent


def power_of_three( x ):
    lastHexDigit = x & 0xF
    if lastHexDigit == 0x1:
       k = power_of_eightyone( x )
       if k >= 0: return 4 * k
    elif lastHexDigit == 0x3:
       xnew = x // 3
       if xnew * 3 == x:
           k = power_of_eightyone( xnew )
           if k >= 0: return 4 * k + 1
    elif lastHexDigit == 0x9:
       xnew = x // 9
       if xnew * 9 == x:
           k = power_of_eightyone( xnew )
           if k >= 0: return 4 * k + 2
    elif lastHexDigit == 0xB:
       xnew = x // 27
       if xnew * 27 == x:
           k = power_of_eightyone( xnew )
           if k >= 0: return 4 * k + 3
    return -1


print( "\nDoes-it-work test of all natural numbers less than 10 million ..." )
for i in range( 1, 10000000 ):
    k = power_of_three( i )
    if k >= 0: print( i, k )

print( "\nIndividual checks of large numbers ..." )
for k in [ 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 21000000 ]:
    print( k, power_of_three( 3**k ), power_of_three( 3 ** k + 1 ) )

Output:
Pre-computation starts ...
... pre-computation ends

Does-it-work test of all natural numbers less than 10 million ...
1 0
3 1
9 2
27 3
81 4
243 5
729 6
2187 7
6561 8
19683 9
59049 10
177147 11
531441 12
1594323 13
4782969 14

Individual checks of large numbers ...
10 10 -1
100 100 -1
1000 1000 -1
10000 10000 -1
100000 100000 -1
1000000 1000000 -1
10000000 10000000 -1
21000000 21000000 -1

Older Version
I'm indebted to no comment for his python try-out code in a comment.
A necessary (but not sufficient) condition for x to be an even power of n is that x%(n^2-1) is 1, whilst a necessary (but not sufficient) condition for x to be an odd power of n is is that x%(n^2-1) is n. This allows one (a) to rapidly reject many numbers and (b) recurse accordingly to find out if x is a power of n^2 or x/n is a power of n^2.
The tests are always much quicker to reject as false than accept as true - which isn't necessarily true of some other answers.
def test( n, x ):                      # is x a power of n
    if x == 1 or x == n: return True
    if x % n != 0: return False

    nsq = n * n
    residue = x % ( nsq - 1 )
    if   residue == 1: return test( nsq, x      )
    elif residue == n: return test( nsq, x // n )
    return False


def isPowerOf3( x ):
    lastDigit = x % 10
    if lastDigit == 1: 
       return test( 81, x )
    elif lastDigit == 7 and x % 27 == 0:
       return test( 81, x // 27 )
    elif lastDigit == 9 and x % 9 == 0:
       return test( 81, x // 9 )
    elif lastDigit == 3 and x % 3 == 0:
       return test( 81, x // 3 )
    return False


for i in range( 10000000 ):
    if ( isPowerOf3( i ) ): print( i )
    
print( isPowerOf3( 3**100000     ) )
print( isPowerOf3( 3**100000 + 1 ) )
print( isPowerOf3( 3**1000000     ) )
print( isPowerOf3( 3**1000000 + 1 ) )


You mistook "numbers up to 10^7 digits long" for "numbers up to 10^7".

@wim Clearly not. See the last two lines in the code, testing 3**100000 and 3**100000 + 1.

@lastchance Somewhat similar and seems faster.

@wim, the first test was just a quick "does it work?" test. I didn't actually count the zeros, so it's a fluke that it was 10^7. I just let it run up to a size where I could still tell in my head whether one value was 3 times the previous one.

Note my n % 8 == 3 check to check whether it would have to be an odd power of 3. Maybe you could do something similar, so that you wouldn't have to try two recursive calls but just the appropriate one.

Thanks; yes I'll look at it. It would certainly be nice not to have to spawn two recursive calls at each stage.

Some times with yours: isPowerOf3(81**8192) takes about 0.008 seconds, while isPowerOf3(81**8191) takes about 14 seconds.

That's certainly a revelation! I'll try to sort out the better recursive calls.

The biggest number you tested was 47713 digits long, orders of magnitude smaller than 10000000.  Am I missing something?

@wim You're missing that that's much much larger than "numbers up to 10^7".

No, I didn't miss that. It's not nearly large enough, not even close.

@wim Your claim is You mistook "numbers up to 10^7 digits long" for "numbers up to 10^7".. Which is clearly not the case, as they did test numbers far beyond the latter, more like the former. Why did you make that claim then, if you didn't miss that?

Because the loop went up to 10^7. User says that was a fluke/coincidence, but I'm not sure I buy it. I disagree with your assessment that the largest number tested was "more like the former". It's much closer to 0 than to any 10^7 digit number.

@wim Both 10^47713 and 10^10000000 are huge, the latter just huger. And 10^7 is nothing like them. A solution that can quickly handle 10^47713 might also handle 10^10000000 in a reasonable time. A solution designed just for 10^7 likely doesn't. It's a completely different ball game. The 3**100000 btw might've originated from me. Another answer had claimed "instantaneous" results, so I commented that just 3**100000 already took 7 seconds.

I'm a bit tired of the discussion. We now have 5 answers here, one which is not obviously better than the idea O.P. already had in their question, and 4 which are clearly worse. I don't know why people bother to post answers that are clearly worse. Any answers that don't provide anything useful will be downvoted by me, with a comment.

@wim Any working solution is better than the OP's code, which doesn't work.

nneonneo has posted a slightly modified version of the O.P. idea, and I am convinced it is working.  Are you not convinced? Do you have a counter-example to offer?

@wim I can't execute their "idea". What even is their "idea", exactly? I'm sure I can find a counter-example for their code.

@wim For example, 3**21 - 1 is no power of 3, but the OP's code returns 21. How do you fix their code while keeping their "idea"?

The idea is using logarithms to estimate the solution.  If 3^x = N then x = log(N) / log(3). Yeah O.P. code was not working perfectly, but fixing it while keeping the same basic idea is what nneonneo already did. He's arguing that float64 data type is sufficient for numbers of the magnitude we're interested in. Do you have a real counter-example?

@wim The OP's idea is to approximately compute the logarithm and check whether it's (approximately) an integer. Computing the power and comparing with the input is not the OP's idea.

We may have to agree to disagree. I see this as a minor extension of the OP's idea - taking an almost working code and making it working. The important part is to transform large numbers into the log domain.

Many thanks, @no comment. I (generalised from) your code link and got the recursions down to spawning one per call instead of 2. For my tests it made a big improvement. You might want to put up your own code as an answer. I'd still like to do something directly from powers of 81 rather than 3, but my numerology hasn't quite got me that far yet.

Yep, that's how I modified it as well. And then I dropped the 81. And yes, I might still post an answer, but I'm waiting for the OP to respond. Then I might have a solution for their task much faster than what has been posted so far.

I think @wim is ultimately correct. The value of 3**100000 is 47713 digits (or about 4.7 x 10^4 digits), and 3**1000000 +1 is 477121 digits (or about 4.7 x 10^5 digits), neither of which is close to 10,000,000 digits (or about 1.0 x 10^7 digits). 3**21000000 seems to resolve into something close to 10^7 number of digits.

Accepted - it has a little way to go. I’m still searching for improvements that get the extra digits within a credible time … but haven’t got there yet. The solution of no comment which works with n and isqrt(x) is better than my n^2 and x.

"He wanted to store ALL powers of 3, but, in fact, you only need to store a few of them" - That's not right. We don't need to store any. And for M.C. Escher's goal of optimal query time complexity, we likely do need to store all of them.

@Randall Arms, my modified code has now reached the required digit limit.

"The biggest number you tested was 47713 digits long" - @wim, that is now fixed.

@lastchance Much better!

If you wanted to check for a power of 10, it would be easy - convert to a string, verify the left-most digit is 1 and all the others are 0, and return the number of digits minus one.
You can use the same approach for powers of 3, by converting the number to base 3.  All you need is an efficient way of converting to base 3, and fortunately that's a problem I've already solved.
def number_to_base(n, b):
    if n < b:
        return [n]
    else:
        digits = [d for x in number_to_base(n, b*b) for d in divmod(x, b)]
        return digits if digits[0] else digits[1:]

def is_power_of_three(N):
    digits = number_to_base(N, 3)
    if digits[0] == 1 and all(digit == 0 for digit in digits[1:]):
        return len(digits) - 1
    return -1

Of course you could optimize this by short-circuiting the conversion as soon as you detect a non-zero digit, the only case where you need the full conversion is when the number really is a power of 3.

Let's consider a very different direction in the design space.
Suppose you have terabytes of RAM on your system that's implementing this algorithm, and you are able to wait a relatively long time up front before your system needs to serve queries. Then one possibility to consider would be to trade space for time. One naive implementation would be to build a dictionary that contains all of the precomputed powers. For example
import numpy as np
from typing import Callable, Optional, Dict

def power_of(d:int, max_power:int = 1000) -> Callable[[int], Optional[int]]:
    powers: Dict[int, int] = {d**p : p for p in range(max_power)}
    def _power_of(n:int) -> Optional[int]:
        if n not in powers:
            return None
        return powers[n]
    return _power_of

power_of_three = power_of(d=3)
for n in [3**7, 31, 3**17, 19, 3**717, 2]:
    if power_of_three(n):
        print(f'{n} = 3**{power_of_three(n)} is a power of three.')

2187 = 3**7 is a power of three.
129140163 = 3**17 is a power of three.
1247210142657768550234499905378922116639451366898087312538538177183283277190295683103245730147060600435233370573683741514365244344103300612526103762013933988624958845627312726170516719777795450552811978287456535513735132589906307717618776994011974474023199537901774015724645671942512194978081587203777687270179262688182385232237326839103742163 = 3**717 is a power of three.

Here, power_of is a higher order procedure that generates a power_of_d function that will answer queries of the form "is n a power of d for n in range(1, d**max_power), where d and max_power are the parameters to power_of. Not surprisingly, even this naive implementation is quite fast (once we have built our table). For example, let us compare to @nneonneo's much more practical implementation:
import math

def power_of_three_log(n):
   if n <= 0:
       return -1
   k = math.floor(n.bit_length() * (math.log(2) / math.log(3)))
   if n == 3**k:
       return k
   else:
       return -1

n = 3**717
%timeit power_of_three(n)
263 ns ± 0.694 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

%timeit power_of_three_log(n)
1.15 µs ± 70.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

This may all seem silly, and admittedly there is something to that feeling, nevertheless there is also something to be said about exploring the design space. For example, if you are designing a chip for a resource constrained environment, perhaps you can't afford to implement a carry look-ahead or a parallel-prefix adder, but you do have plenty of time for your computation. Then you might consider trading time for space and implement your adders using a bit-serial adder! 
This adder may take n cycles to add two n-bit numbers, however I challenge you to implement an adder that takes less space. Furthermore, it can add numbers of arbitrary dimension!

How many terabytes would they need?

Not feasible for the data mentioned in the question (numbers up to 10^7 digits long)

@wim Why not, in the clearly stated scenario of "Suppose you have terabytes of RAM [...] and you are able to wait a relatively long time up front"?

@nocomment Today I don't have the time, but I could do some back-of-the-napkin arithmetic and get back to you. I remember that a quick computation convinced me that you could  lay down a table in under ~50 TB. However, if the OP was genuinely interested in this solution, you would optimize it in myriad ways. You could probably key create a compact representation for hashing these numbers. Assuming less than 10**7 digits, the max power of three is less than 3**2.1e7: however on my system, Python still requires over 4MB to represent this number.

@wim Why precisely is this solution not feasible for numbers up to 10^7 digits long? What do you mean by not feasible? The dictionary would be of a reasonable size (fewer than 2.1e7 entries), the values would be ordinary integers, and even in a naive implementation, the keys are each bounded in size by 5MB.

Moreover, you could precompute the table once and for all and serialize it to an external device, eliminating the need to recompute when the server restarts. The problem is a question of set-membership, in particular set membership for a fixed set of positive integers, and therefore a design that implements a task-specific lookup table is a reasonable direction to explore. It is this kind of thinking that leads to data structures such as the Van Emde Boas Tree.

Yeah after some tests I estimated ~47 TB as well, and ~10 hours to build (not with ** but with repeated *= 3).

I didn’t say impossible, I said not feasible.  It’s a bad idea (wasteful, inefficient, expensive) when no meaningful advantage over the log computation based approach has been demonstrated.

@wim I'd say serving queries much faster can be a meaningful advantage (depends on the user's needs). Looks like the log-way would take up to ~15 seconds per query while this would take up to ~0.004 seconds. Do you mean that should be demonstrated in the answer? I think it's already clear that it's much faster, just not clear how much.

The computational complexity of an algorithm is a fundamental consideration in the design process. To further clarify, a key idea in my answer is the exploration of algorithms that trade space for time and vice-versa. Certainly on both ends of the spectrum, you will have design points with significantly different characteristics. In optimization terminology, this algorithm design problem is a multi-criterion or multi-objective problem, with two scalar objectives (and likely more), of finding a (correct) algorithm that minimizes space and minimizes time.

If there is a point (an algorithm) in the feasible set that strictly dominates all the other feasible points (according to our objectives of space and time), then we would say the objectives are noncompeting. Then the problem is easy. Usually though, this is not the case, and there is a set of Pareto Optimal points located on the optimal trade-off surface which can not be strictly compared: in this case any chosen point requires a compromise in one of the directions in the search space. This is an inherent difficulty often encountered in system design.

The family of algorithms I am suggesting have an algorithmic complexity of O(1): this is average-case complexity if we use a standard dict, but as I just remembered, it is possible to make this O(1) worst-case time! Given that the set of keys is static, we can implement the table using Perfect Hashing, as described in section 11.5 of Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen et al..

How is it O(1) instead of Theta(log n)?

@nocomment  Last time that I checked, a Python dict is a hash table that resolves collisions using the technique of chaining, and the average time complexity is O(1) for a Chained-Hash-Search operation.  Take a look at chapter 11 of CLRS, or any other standard textbook on Algorithm Design and Analysis. Of course, this depends on the hash function being used, which I have not looked up, and I am assuming the developers have chosen a reasonable hash function for integer types.

Computing the hash of int n takes Theta(log n) time. Then looking up the hash in the dict takes O(1) average. Finally, checking that not only the hash matches but that the key is indeed equal takes another Theta(log n) if it is. Overall Theta(log n).

@nocomment Indeed, you are right, thank you for correcting me. In regards to the complexity of power_of_three, this scheme is indeed most likely linear in the number of bits of the input, depending on our choice of hash function. Nevertheless, it is an important detail that you can implement the table such that Hash-Search is O(1) in relation to the number of keys.

Python could implement ints so that they hash in O(1), but I don't see any way around the O(log n) for the comparison to rule out hash collisions. (Well, I guess Python could auto-intern all ints and do int-equality-checks by identity, but I don't see that happening :-)

When I said it doesn't matter how fast you make the hash lookup, I meant how much faster you make it than what you already have. Which might already be O(1) worst case, judging by Dillon's answer and Python's dict implementation. I didn't mean it doesn't matter how slow you make it. Yes, of course if you make it slower than those other two parts, then it matters.

Actually you can use Dillon's observation of powers of 3 not colliding modulo a sufficiently large power of 2. For n up to 10^7 digits, 2^27 suffices. Don't use a dict, use a list table of length 2^27. Store the i-th power in table[3**i & (2**27-1)]. Then for a query, look up table[n & (2**27-1)] and compare it with n. This way, both the hashing and the lookup are O(1) in all cases (in CPython, at least). Only comparing the exact value still takes O(log n).

@nocomment That is a very nice idea for the hash table! Returning to the analysis, though, really the algorithmic complexity is a function of d, the maximum number of digits allowed, which was specified for this instance to be d = 10**7. My proposed family of algorithms is O(d), whereas the accepted answer has a worst-case complexity of O(d^1.58 lg d), with the lg d term from the exponentiation and the d^1.58 because the last time I checked, Python uses Karatsuba's algorithm for multiplication of large integers.

I suspect the accepted answer is O(d^1.58). Runtime is probably dominated by just the one largest multiplication.

To check the power p of a number n, you can convert this number to the base p and check if the first digit (on the left) is 1, and the remaining digits are 0.
x = 3**100000
y = x - 1
z = x - 9
a = 30

def ternary (n):
    if n == 0:
        return '0'
    nums = []
    while n:
        n, r = divmod(n, 3)
        nums.append(str(r))
    return ''.join(reversed(nums))

def is_power_of_3(n):
    nstr = ternary(n)
    return nstr[0] == '1' and '1' not in nstr[1:] and '2' not in nstr[1:]

print("x = {}\ny = {}\nz = {}\na = {}".format(is_power_of_3(x), is_power_of_3(y), is_power_of_3(z), is_power_of_3(a)))

I gave 4 examples, only x is a power of 3.
Output:
x = True
y = False
z = False
a = False

real    2.60s
user    2.59s
sys     0.01s
cpu     99%

With only one value to test:
x = True

real    0.88s
user    0.87s
sys     0.01s
cpu     99%


You missed this part: The challenge is that ( N ) can be extremely large, with up to ( 10^7 ) digits

@wim - I had already admit the answer of nneonno is far more efficient. But I still find my approach interesting. And can treat up to 10^5 digits numbers quite efficiently, not so bad

It is interesting, but it doesn't answer the question. I would use numpy.base_repr(n, 3) rather than a Python loop.

@wim That seems to be two times slower, though (tests).

Oh, well I guess numpy also uses a Python loop then ...

@wim Most of the time is spent inside divmod, the Python loop doesn't matter much. Don't know what NumPy is doing to be that much slower. This could be sped up by divmodding not by 3 but by 3^18 and handling each block of 18 digits. But... of course it would still not be good. And more complicated. Would be better for Chris's, barely more complicated and would become about 36 times faster, I think.

If you're going to repeatedly divmod by 3, you might as well directly test if the remainder is zero, instead of building a string. E.g. if one of the remainders is 2, you don't need to keep going. So this is just worse than the obvious, direct solution (e.g. like this).

@kaya3 This is probably still twice as fast as that for large powers of 3.

@nocomment How do you expect "divmod in a loop, build a string, test the string" to be faster than "divmod in a loop"?

@kaya3 The one you referenced doesn't use divmod.

@nocomment The one I referenced is just to show an example of the logic, and my comment clearly says "if you're going to repeatedly divmod by 3".
